# Getting the top-K values of a tensor using TensorFlow C API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have two vectors of double values in C++: `std::vector<double> vec_a; std::vector<double> vec_b;`. I want to do pairwise multiplications of these two vectors, to get `K^2` values; and next take the top-K values from this product.

Since pairwise multiplication is an expensive operation, I want to do the above on the GPU. And it also needs to use the TensorFlow C APIs. There's very limited documentation of TensorFlow C API. Can anyone help me with writing the above code?

Comment: Never used TensorFlow, but to get the top K-items doesn't require you to generate all the results first and store them (if this is what you were intending to do).  A min-heap of K items is all you need to accomplish this at the same time you're computing each product.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. You are absolutely right, but I think in TensorFlow C API it wouldn't be so easy to use a min-heap.

Comment: Well, I thought maybe you could use `std::make_heap` and the rest of the C++ heap functions.  The heap will definitely save the space (you won't need n^2 values stored somewhere, only K additional values), but you will have to code one up yourself.